# How to map an entity property with an object coming from a list of objects of another entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, model-associations

I can't figure out which is the best approach to map an entity property with a selected object that coming from a list of objects stored in a different entity.

Example Use Case:

- I have an `AccountType` entity with 5 account types (*I need to have an entity because it will have many associations and properties like enabled, etc...*).
- I have an `User` entity with the `$accountType` property.
- The `User` can select only one `AccountType` (*using a form*).

Question:

Which is the common way to map the `User:accountType` property? Considering that then I will need to retrieve some statistical data as retrieve all users that belongs to a each account type and so on.

Should I map the `$accountType` as `string` and use a [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) to estrapolate the string or exist some other method like map `$accountType` using a oneToOne association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common. You need a ManyToOne relationship.

```
class User
{
    //...

    /**
     * Many Users will have One AccountType
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AccountType")
     */
    private $accountType;


    /**
     * @return AccountType
     */
    public function getAccountType()
    {
        return $this->accountType;
    }
}
```

You can then get to the accountType object tied to your user like so:

```
$user->getAccountType(); // AccountType object
```

Depending on your needs, you may want to define a bidirectional relationship (i.e., define a OneToMany relationship in your AccountType entity). That would allow you to do something like:

```
$accountType->getUsers();
```

This would take just a little more work in your entities but is really powerful with only a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I haven't yet the time to go really deep studing the docs and looking your answer it seems the right way for this case. To complete the answer, can you add a very simple/common case/example in which I should use a DataTransformer and use the other approach? (not the full code but a only a bit with a sintetic explanation). I will come back in few hours :-)

Comment: I've not used DataTransformer, but I don't think it's what you want since you have an AccountType entity. The example in the DataTransformer page that you linked has a property (tags) that is stored as an array. If you opted for this approach you lose access (from User) to the properties on the linked AccountType unless you jump through some other hoops to create an object. Why do that if you can get it all automagically?